# Convert DICOM to JPG - ERROR

Tags: c#, dicom

I'm using DICOM#(http://sourceforge.net/projects/dicom-cs/) to convert a dicom file (.dcm) to a .jpg.
The code i've done:

```
string strFileName = nomeFile;
string strOutFileName = Server.MapPath("uploads/" + "teste");
Stream ins = null;
Dataset ds = null;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
System.IO.Stream strm = fs;

Dataset imgds;
imgds = new Dataset();
imgds.ReadFile(strm, FileFormat.DICOM_FILE, 10000);

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = imgds.GetByteBuffer(Tags.PixelData);
byte[] byteArray = (byte[])byteBuffer.ToArray();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
strOutFileName = strOutFileName + ".PNG";
returnImage.Save(strOutFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

But this give me an error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

In this line:

```
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Title says JPG, code says PNG. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in decoding the image from the stream. An `ArgumentException` is unfortunately a very generic error that System.Drawing classes throw when the underlying GDI library can't deal with what you give it. I'd suspect one of:

1. You don't have all the bytes in the array that you create from `ByteBuffer` so `Image.FromStream` can't decode it
2. The data from `ByteBuffer` is too large for GDI to make an image from
3. The data is not a known image format, and `Image.FromStream` can't decode it. (e.g. is it Raw pixel data? If so, you have to build the image differently, by writing the pixel bytes to the encoder)

**Extra tip:**

Using 10000 for the buffer size passed to `ReadFile` is not optimal. Blocks read from the underlying filesystem are a multiple of 4096 bytes, and a best-fit buffer will have the same multiple. See: [Optimum file buffer read size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552107/optimum-file-buffer-read-size).

Comment: See the other Dicom image pixel module attributes (Dicom C.7-11 http://dicomlookup.com/lookup.asp?sw=Ttable&q=C.7-11 ) in the dicom file you're trying to read for the actual stored format.

Comment: Sounds like a good practice, but `Image.FromStream` should decode it if it is a well known (i.e. supported by GDI) encoding.

Comment: DICOM appears to use raw pixel data, or did I misintrepret table C.7-11?

Comment: @codekaizen It can work but windows does not ship with a DICOM handler for GDI. It will only work if you install a handler for it (I don't know if DICOM# does that or not)